# Is /etc/auto.net right? Seems like a typo

Tags: nfs, automounting, autofs, hang

Like many people I've had trouble with machines hanging when the NFSv3 server was not available (switched off). I saw various suggestions , like soft/hard , intr, bg etc being set... not a lot seems to work so I went back the the start. /etc/auto.net is a script run to determine what can be automatically mounted . Looking at the script it seemed pretty safe to run it just outputs a string. I have a NAS with the CNAME of "nas" (original I know):

```
graeme@real:/etc$ MOUNT_NFS_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL=4 ./auto.net nas
-fstype=nfs4,hard,intr,nodev,nosuid,async nas:/
graeme@real:/etc$ MOUNT_NFS_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL=3 ./auto.net nas
 \
    /Download nas:/Download \
    /InternalAdmin nas:/InternalAdmin \
    /Multimedia nas:/Multimedia \
    /Public nas:/Public \
    /Recordings nas:/Recordings \
    /USBUploads nas:/USBUploads \
    /Web nas:/Web \
    /git nas:/git \
    /homes nas:/homes \
    /svn nas:/svn
```

As you see, for NFSv4 it outputs mount options followed by the NFSv4 export. For NFSv3  it just lists the exports (no options) if you look at the script however you see:

```
SHOWMOUNT="$SMNT --no-headers -e $key"

    $SHOWMOUNT | LC_ALL=C cut -d' ' -f1 | LC_ALL=C sort -u | \
        awk -v key="$key" -v opts="$opts" -- '
        BEGIN   { ORS=""; first=1 }
            { if (first) { print opts; first=0 }; print " \\\n\t" $1, key ":" $1 }
        END { if (!first) print "\n"; else exit 1 }
        ' | sed 's/#/\\#/g'
    opts="-fstype=nfs,hard,intr,nodev,nosuid"
else
    # NFSv4
    opts="-fstype=nfs4,hard,intr,nodev,nosuid,async"

    echo "$opts $key:/"
fi
```

The bit before the else is NFSv3 and the else is NFSv4...as you see NFSv4 sets opts then echos $opts then $key, Whereas NFSv3 sets opts in the same way **but then does not use it**.

I wonder if assignment of opt was intended to be earlier, nowadays, preferably if the form:

```
: ${opts:="-fstype=nfs,hard,intr,nodev,nosuid"}
```

If I do this I get:

```
graeme@real:/etc$ MOUNT_NFS_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL=3 /tmp/auto.net nas
-fstype=nfs,hard,intr,nodev,nosuid \
    /Download nas:/Download \
    /InternalAdmin nas:/InternalAdmin \
    /Multimedia nas:/Multimedia \
    /Public nas:/Public \
    /Recordings nas:/Recordings \
    /USBUploads nas:/USBUploads \
    /Web nas:/Web \
    /git nas:/git \
    /homes nas:/homes \
    /svn nas:/svn
```

Comment: this is Debian trixie, but I think it's quite widespread

Comment: Seems like a buggy bugfix applied three years ago: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=646625 https://salsa.debian.org/debian/autofs/-/commit/7a40723a9828692b8c379ae05bd7171ade1c997a

Comment: Do you happen to know the mechanism to report this?  I'm assuming an identified commit is different to just "bug in package X"

Comment: FYI Found an old stretch system ...  it does work as above ... but the options still don't seem to get used:


$ bash /etc/auto.net nas
-fstype=nfs,hard,intr,nodev,nosuid \
 /Download nas:/Download \
 /InternalAdmin nas:/InternalAdmin \
 ..elided..
$ mount | grep Download
-hosts on /net/nas/Download type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=6,pgrp=793,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,offset,pipe_ino=18488)
nas:/Download on /net/nas/Download type nfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.117.1.161,mount...